# Creating SerializerMethodField fields dynamically

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models Ticket and Staff in my heldepdesk service. Ticket has a ForeignKey link to Staff. I need to count how many succeeded tickets every helpdesk worker had in certain period of time. For example, I am asked to give statistic for May and June. At another time, I might be asked to give information for September, October and November, so every time the amount of months might be different.

I want to count tickets with SerializerMethodField

Something like this:

```
class TicketByPeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    may_tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    june_tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
         model = Staff
         fields = ["may_tickets", "june_tickets"]

    
    def get_may_tickets(self, instance):
        "some logic"

    def june_tickets(self, instance):
        "some logic"
```

But how can I handle the dynamic creation of SerializerMethodField?

Answer (score 0):

I would filter and aggregate the queryset and let the serializer handle the serialization. i.e something like (sorry writing from top of my head without access to test the code):

```
class TicketsByPeriodSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    month = serializers.CharField()
    count = serializers.IntegerField()


class TicketSummaryView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TicketByPeriodSerializer
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", some_sane_default)
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", some_sane_default)
        
        qs = qs.filter(
            resolving_user=self.request.user,
            state="succeeded",
            resolved_at__range=(start_date, end_date)
          )
          .annotate(month=TruncMonth("resolved_at"))
          .values("month")
          .annotate(count=Count("id"))
          .order_by("month")
        return qs
```

then call with `GET /myview/?start_date=2022-06-01&end_date=2022-10-01`